# How to create html with JavaScript? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, null

I want to create a date/time under my weeks, in columns like this:

```
Mon       Tuesday......
```

And  I want in row to be shown date/time from 9 AM until 5 PM. Like this:

```
Mon       Tuesday
09:00
09:30
.
.
.
.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have 2 arrays

```
var days = [
  'Monday',
  'Tuesday',
  'Wednesday',
  'Thursday',
  'Friday'
];

var hours = [
  '09:00',
  '09:30',
  '10:00',
  '10:30',
  '11:00',
  '11:30',
  '12:00',
  '12:30',
  '13:00',
  '13:30',
  '14:00',
  '14:30',
  '15:00',
  '15:30',
  '16:00',
  '16:30',
  '17:00'
];
```

I already made my days to be shown inline next to each other with JavaScript, but I can't make it to work with the time:

```
function createTable(roomName) {
    var table = '';
    //for loop for days
    for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
        //checking if the value is  Monday
        if (i === 0) {
            table = table +  '<div class="inDays"> <h2>' + days[i] + '</h2>';
        } else {
            table = table +  '<div class="inDays nxt"> <h2>' + days[i] + '</h2>';
        }
        table = table + '</div>';
    } document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = table;
    var hrs = '';
    for (var z = 0; z < hours.length; z++) {
        if (z === 0) {
            hrs = hrs + '<div id="hr"> <span>' + hours[z] + '</span>';
        } else {
            hrs = hrs + '<div id="hr"> <span>' + hours[z] + '</span>';
        }
        hrs = hrs + '</div>';
    } document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML = hrs;
}
```

I do have my JavaScript before the closing `body` tag,
and also have `hr` id in HTML.

```
<div class="hours" >
    <div id="hr">

    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `#days` element in DOM

```js
createTable();

function createTable(roomName) {
  var days = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday'
  ];

  var hours = [
    '09:00',
    '09:30',
    '10:00',
    '10:30',
    '11:00',
    '11:30',
    '12:00',
    '12:30',
    '13:00',
    '13:30',
    '14:00',
    '14:30',
    '15:00',
    '15:30',
    '16:00',
    '16:30',
    '17:00'
  ];

  var table = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      table = table + '<div class="inDays"> <h2>' + days[i] + '</h2>';
    } else {
      table = table + '<div class="inDays nxt"> <h2>' + days[i] + '</h2>';
    }
    table = table + '</div>';

  }
  document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = table;
  var hrs = '';
  for (var z = 0; z < hours.length; z++) {
    if (z === 0) {
      hrs = hrs + '<div id="hr"> <span>' + hours[z] + '</span>';
    } else {
      hrs = hrs + '<div id="hr"> <span>' + hours[z] + '</span>';
    }
    hrs = hrs + '</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML = hrs;
}
```

```html
<div class="hours">
  <div id="days">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hours">
  <div id="hr">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Simplified code:**

```js
createTable();

function createTable(roomName) {
  var days = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday'
  ];

  var hours = [
    '09:00',
    '09:30',
    '10:00',
    '10:30',
    '11:00',
    '11:30',
    '12:00',
    '12:30',
    '13:00',
    '13:30',
    '14:00',
    '14:30',
    '15:00',
    '15:30',
    '16:00',
    '16:30',
    '17:00'
  ];

  var table = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      table += '<div class="inDays"> <h2>' + days[i] + '</h2></div>';
    } else {
      table += '<div class="inDays nxt"> <h2>' + days[i] + '</h2></div>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('days').innerHTML = table;
  var hrs = '';
  for (var z = 0; z < hours.length; z++) {
    if (z === 0) {
      hrs += '<div id="hr"> <span>' + hours[z] + '</span></div>';
    } else {
      hrs += '<div id="hr"> <span>' + hours[z] + '</span></div>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML = hrs;
}
```

```css
.nxt {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="hours">
  <div id="days">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="hours">
  <div id="hr">
  </div>
</div>
```